# Magento 2: Message displays After disable Product Review Module "Attention: Something went wrong"

Tags: magento2, product, admin, review, bug

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.1.

As per requirement i don't need "Product Review" Module. So i disable from Admin & Clear Cache

When i Edit any of the Admin Product then it says

> "Attention: Something went wrong"

If i enable Product Review Module again then it works fine.

On product detail page we have "**Product Reviews**" tab, may be they are not checking.

If Review Module is Disabled then we don't need to show this tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just set 0 value for review module.

Go to file,

**`magento2/app/etc/config.php`**

```
 'Magento_Review' => 0
```

So your error are gone and your review module functionality are stopped working.

Comment: I have done `php bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content Magento_Review` then `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. So it should do automatically or we have to it manually this step?

Comment: its automatically disable, you have to look inside app/etc/config.php file